# User listed as member of wheel group, but is not in passwd

Tags: linux, group

Does a user account listed as a member of the wheel group, but is not defined in passwd have any meaningful access to the system? I suspect this is an 'artifact' of accounts removed from passwd in the past. The accounts are no longer defined anywhere that I can find.

Comment: Read `man getent nsswitch.conf`, and try `getent passwd theuserid` to retrieve the password file entry the way the system does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using an external source such as LDAP, NIS, or NIS+ to obtain user data in addition to /etc/passwd, there is no access for an account listed in /etc/group which does not exist in /etc/passwd.

However, for cleanliness, the entry should be removed from /etc/group anyway, in case the same user name is reused in the future for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that it was a cleanliness thing. If the account existed in LDAP, but was not in passwd, there is some way that it could be used to logon?